# AdMob NativeAd not showing in emulator without Google Play

Tags: android, admob, android-virtual-device, native-ads, google-native-ads

I am trying to test **NativeAd** with emulator and it works fine except for those virtual device that have no Play Store. AVD tablets do not have Play Store, you can only use images with Google API but it will not have Play Services.

[image]

**Banner** and **Interstitial** Ads work despite a device having no Play Store, how to test **NativeAd** in this scenario where Play Store/Google Play is not available in both virtual device and image?